# Bruhat decomposition and standard Frobenius

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, schubert-varieties

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group define over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$, consider it as a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(n)$. Let $F_p$ be the standard Frobenius. Let $B$ and $Q$ be an $F_p$-stable Borel subgroup and $F_p$-stable parabolic subgroup respectively with $B\subset Q$. Let $\bigcup_{w\in W^{Q}} BwQ/Q$ be the Bruhat decomposition of $G/Q$. Where $W^{Q}$ is the Weyl group of $Q$.

My question: Is the Schubert cell $BwQ/Q$ $F_p$-stable? For the case $G=\operatorname{SL}(n)$?

Comment: Do you mean by $W^Q$ the group $N_{G^{F_p}}(M)/M^{F_p}$, for $M$ a Levi component of $Q$?  If so, then this is trivial, so you must not; but then I don't know what you do mean.  (Also, please use "$F_p$-stable" `$F_p$-stable`, not "$F_p-$stable" `$F_p-$stable`.  I have edited accordingly.)

Comment: @LSpice :Dear LSpice, https://mathoverflow.net/q/195456/147080 I just use the notation of this question

Comment: [That](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424114/bruhat-decomposition-and-standard-frobenius#comment1090252_424114) link also unfortunately doesn't define it.  A common definition is $W^Q = N_{G^{F_p}}(M)/M^{F_p}$ (and then the decomposition holds as desired), in which case the result is obvious; so, if you want to use some other definition, then you'll need to say what it is.

Comment: Thanks.  But if it defined over $\mathbb{C}$, then how to define $W^Q$?

Comment: I think I may realise what I wasn't seeing.  You are assuming that $B$ and $Q$, but not $G$, are defined over $\mathbb F_p$?  (I'm not sure what you mean by asking about $\mathbb C$, since we're over $\overline{\mathbb F_p}$ here; maybe you mean to replace $(\overline{\mathbb F_p}, F_p)$ by $(\mathbb C, \text{conjugation})$?)